# Software for managing SAAS subscriptions

Tags: saas

We are planning to launch a software-as-as-service solution. The software is well under way.

In addition to the actual business application, there is plenty of "meta" functionality required to offer SAAS, such as

- creating a landing page
- receiving orders
- processing (recurring)   payments
- generating payment reports
- managing the account
- etc

I.e. functionality that every SAAS software has.

Are there any (preferable open source) platforms or tools to manage all this?